# Using PostgreSQL Case When with Partition

Tags: sql, postgresql, case, window-functions

I am trying to use `Case when` with partition to create a new row and mark whether its duplicated or not

My desired output is shown below

[image]

The query I am using

I cant find the error here. It seemed to work in SQL Server before

```
SELECT *,
    CASE 
        WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 
            x , y > 1) THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE
    END AS is_duplicated
    FROM users
```

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: You've tagged SQL Server, but in your title mention PostgreSQL - which is it?

Comment: @DaleK . . . Based on the query, which uses `TRUE` and `FALSE` as boolean values, I guess it should be PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `> 1` should be out of `(PARTITIONBY x, y)` like this:

```
SELECT *,
    CASE 
        WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 
            x , y) > 1 THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE
    END AS is_duplicated
    FROM users
```

Comprasion operator itself results on boolean, so you don't need case:

```
SELECT *,
     
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 
            x , y) > 1
     AS is_duplicated
    FROM users
```

But this will result, marking duplicate only the rows after the first row, meaning first `Carlo Thomas` will not be duplicate.

So for the desired result, you need this:

```
SELECT *,
     
       (SELECT count(*) from users t WHERE t.x=u.x and t.y=u.y) > 1
     AS is_duplicated
    FROM users u;
```

Comment: Perhaps it is the OP's purpose to mark all duplicates except the first one as a duplicate. I cannot tell anything about that, so I just have to assume the OP knows what they are doing. However, for determining the correct first row in the group/partition, I would also expect a `ORDER BY` (probably based on primary key value) inside the `OVER` section so that the correct record will be detected as the first one.

Comment: @BartHofland Yes, question is a bit unclear. That's why I gave two answer one was the small fix for his query, and the second for desired output.

Answer (score 1):

As the two other answers point out, the `>` is not part of the `partition by`.

I want to point out first that using `row_number()` without `order by` is highly, highly discouraged.  Without an order by, the result can be different on each run.

More importantly, you don't want `row_number()`.  You want `count()` -- because you want `TRUE` on *all* rows where there are duplicates.

The second is that a `case` expression is not necessary at all, because Postgres has a boolean type.

So:

```
SELECT u.*,
       (COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY x, y) > 1) AS is_duplicated
FROM users u;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=5f28f0c00cc5785c698172c9f420be71) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you put a parenthesis wrong. Could you try `CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY x , y) > 1 THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END`?

By the way, in PostgreSQL, I guess you could write this as well:

```
SELECT
    *,
    (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY x , y) > 1) AS is_duplicated
FROM
    users
```

Note that if you want to make sure that the correct rows are marked as duplicates, you might also want to include an `ORDER BY` in your `OVER` clause.

By the way, when testing this query in Microsoft SQL Server, I get an error message if I omit the `ORDER BY` in the `OVER` clause. It does work fine without an `ORDER BY` in PostgreSQL, however.